# Editing an XML template file recursively

Tags: python, xml

I have an XML file (demodata.xml) which contains some data as given.

```
<data>
<country name="Peru">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>1.21$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="06">141100</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="10">2.304e+0150</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>4.1$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="05">59900</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="08">1.9e-015</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
```

I have one csv file (daily.csv) with the relative path and text of some selected nodes of the XML file as below. Each additional column represents a different set of text values for the selected nodes.

```
Path                                                      Text1,      Text2,      Text3................Text10000..
'/data/country name=singapore/gdpnp month=08';            5.2e-015;   7.0e-015;   10.0e-015; ..
'/data/country name=peru/gdppc month=06';                 0.04;       0.06;       0.12; .. ............ ........                                          .    . 

.
.
.(10000 by 10000 grid)
```

I am new to python/xml. I need a way to read each column into the XML and save with a different file name for each of the columns. Hence, Column 2 will be a new XML file, same with 3 to 10000.

Data from Column 1 will result in a new xml say (demodata1.xml) as below. This will result in 10000 new xml files corresponding to the columns.

```
<data>
<country name="Peru">
    <rank updated="yes">2</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>1.21$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="06">0.04</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="10">2.304e+0150</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Austria" direction="E"/>
    <neighbor name="Switzerland" direction="W"/>
</country>
<country name="Singapore">
    <rank updated="yes">5</rank>
    <language>english</language>
    <currency>4.1$/kg</currency> 
    <gdppc month="05">59900</gdppc>
    <gdpnp month="08">5.2e-015</gdpnp>
    <neighbor name="Malaysia" direction="N"/>
</country>
```

I am not sure how to approach the problem in itself.

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Can you post an example of what you want the XML data to look like? and the complete csv file would be helpful as well.

Comment: Thanks @salparadise I provided an example of what one of the output xmls should look like

Comment: What does recursion have to do with this?

Comment: @Charles Duffy I would like to create new xml files (10000) based on the current file. I thought recursion might be the best way to create subsequent versions of the file.

Comment: ...so, you want to split the large XML file into lots of small XML files. Easy enough (and with a purely iterative algorithm). Where does the CSV file come into play?

Comment: @Charles Duffy Not really. I want to create multiple versions of a single XML file based on the data in the CSV. The first column in the csv represents the paths of the selected text to changed. Each additional column represent the new text to be read into the xml file.

Comment: So do you have one XML file of output per line in the CSV? One per country in the input XML, with changes in the CSV applied? What *exactly* is the relationship between these things?

Comment: At this point, this sounds to me like it should be two separate questions -- one about applying changes from the CSV, and a second, separate question about splitting the input XML.

Comment: @Charles Duffy Yes regards reading in values from the csv. I dont need to split the xml. I am trying to do a monte carlo simulation based on the xml file i.e. create different versions of the xml file based on the path and text in the CSV file.